# CSS Input type=text

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need some help with css on my login.  I want the yellow background color to be transparent when a username is selected, or the two .svg pictures to come over the yellow background.

Two Links of what I mean:

[image]

[image]

I want the svgs of the username and password in the before picture to show in the after picture.

My code

css:

```
.user{
background-image: url("css/user.svg");
background-size: 18px 18px;
background-position: 11px 8px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.pass{
background-image: url("css/pass.svg");
background-size: 18px 18px;
background-position: 11px 8px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

html:

```
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="username" class="user" name="username" />
<input type="password" placeholder="password" class="pass" name="password" />
<input type="submit" value="LOGIN" />
</form>
```

Comment: You'll need a script for that, is that ok?

Comment: It would be great if you could accept an answer, if any, that solve your question, or let us know what is missing, so we can find one that does

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 .user:focus {
      //code here for you images and bg
 }
     // and
.pass:focus{
    //same
}
```

Comment: Nope, same problem.  :(

Comment: Does your svg have a transparent bg?

Comment: Yes, my svg does have a transparent background. :D